# Wordpress local raspbian installation : MySQL crashes once a minute

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, sockets

I've found many similar posts, however I wasn't able to find out a solution, so here is my question.

I've been running since more than one month a local wprdpress installation on Raspbian.

Since yesterday, I always get an error while attempting to tonnect to the website (WP debug mode is ON) :

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1488

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1518

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1518
```

Trying to know more using the command : `mysqladmin -u root -p status`
 gives me :

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I chmoded the folders involved to 755. I don't use `localhost` to name my DB (in `wp-config.php`, in `my.cnf`) but `127.0.0.1`.

If I restart the MySQL service, it works for more or less one minute, then stops again. Using safe-mode didn't work either.

I think this is a socket problem but how can I solve it ?

Comment: What is in your error log file (of mysql) ? Does mysql continues to crash even if you stop your webserver ?

Comment: yes mysql continues to crashe even if I stop my Apache webserver. I've just activated the error log, I'll update my post with the results